# Which software package has the flash plugin for the konqueror web browser?

Tags: flash, plugins, konqueror

I have installed the package that provides a flash plugin to use with firefox
and chromium. (adobe-flash-plugin)

Which software package has the flash plugin for the konqueror web browser?
When konqueror displayed a dialog box saying that there is a flash plugin
to install, I tried to install it using that dialog box but the installation
failed. I wanted to try again using a package manager instead, however I
don't know the name of the package that provides a flash plugin for konqueror.
Which one is it?

Thanks for your help,
Mr. Chris Strubel

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: kubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for(search):

```
apt search konqueror-plugin-gnash
```

To install:

```
sudo apt install konqueror-plugin-gnash
```